# Finding words with consecutive vowels?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

The code is not working: it didn't give any results, I tried solving it without using functions, and that worked fine, but when I used functions then it didn't work.

I think the problem is in passing a 2d array to function. Can you help me understanding where is the issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int cons_vols(char* str, char vol_words[][]);
int is_vol(char);

int main()
{
    /*
    Enter a string to find words with consecutive vowels
    Please Enter password for Authentication
    Words with Consecutive Vowels
    Please
    Authentication
    */
    char str[100] = {0};
    char vol_words[100][100] = {0};
    int totl_vols;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    totl_vols = cons_vols(str, vol_words);
    for(int i=0;i<totl_vols;i++){
        fputs(vol_words[i], stdout);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int cons_vols(char* str, char vol_words[][]) {
    int vols = 0;
    int i = 0;
    //    please enter
    // j =0123456789A
    for(int j= 0; j<strlen(str)-2; j++) {
        if(str[j] == ' ' || str[j] == '\n') {
            i = j+1;
        }
        else {
            if( is_vol(str[j]) && is_vol(str[j+1])) {
                while(str[j] != ' ' && str[j] != '\n' && str[j] != '\0') {
                    j++;
                }
                for(int k=0; k<j-i; k++) {
                     vol_words[vols][k]= str[k+i];
                }
                vols++;
                i = j+1;
            }
        }
    }
    return vols;
}

int is_vol(char ch) {
    if(ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U'
    || ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' )
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you might wanna take a look into `string` and `find_first_of`

Comment: I don't know C++, but I think yours may be an unconventional approach to solving your problem with that language.

Comment: Please pick a language, C or C++.  In C++, this would be a 10 line program, maybe less.

Comment: GIven the question, a [C++ solution would look like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5781feff6009c973)

Answer (score 1):

The array

```
char vol_words[100][100] = {0};
```

is a 100-element array of "100-element array of char".

In C, arrays in function arguments are interpreted as pointer to its element type.

In this case, you are using array of "100-element array of char",
so you should specify that you are using one.

In conclusion, what you should do is to change `char vol_words[][]` (both in declaration and definition) to `char vol_words[][100]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please explain why, what and how

Answer (score 1):

When passing arrays in C, the array name decays into a pointer to the first element. In doing so, it loses the amount of memory allocated to the array.

So effectively the pointer doesn't know where the array ends and might end up accessing / mutating undefined memory locations. To prevent this, an additional parameter, the size of the array is usually passed to the function. In your case, for a 2-D array, the compiler only has access to the first array inside the 2d array. SO to allow the compiler to know the actual bounds of the array, the number of columns in the array is included in the parameter.

You can check [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjj9eTwuZfpAhVDxTgGHdNbDWYQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F12813494%2Fwhy-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter&usg=AOvVaw0buROZEfq4LErlADpBNNEz) thread for a detailed answer.